# Does Linux Mint provide sames packages as Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, packages

i have been using ubuntu 12.04 for quite sometime and was happy until i decided to upgrade to 12.10 which IMO does not match even upto 12.04.. I like gnome and its intuitiveness, so was looking for another linux distro when linux Mint came to my mind. I have been reading on it and came to know that LM is based on Ubuntu.

My question is, if LM is based on Ubuntu, does that mean I get to use any or all of the ubuntu packages on LMint also? Or are there any restrictions imposed by LM on the packages?

Also, would I be able to use the Ubuntu Software Center on Linux Mint? I see they have a different software center, which to me looks like a form of Synaptic Package Manager. I kind of like Ubuntu's SC.

Please also guide me to get the key difference, from a packages point of view, between these two distros. I use Ubuntu for programming so LAMP, sublime text, etc.. are required, then i use Lightread for RSS, etc. I would like to have these in Linux Mint also.

Thanks!

Comment: All that I am looking for is the ease of use in installing the packages. I do not want to compile or do it the manual way. I would prefer the sudo apt-get install model in ubuntu or the simple Software center model of installation. Is this level of simplicity available in Mint also? In general most sites give a Ubuntu version when they give a linux version of the software.. Would such Ubuntu versions work in Linux Mint also? What are the differences?

Answer (score 2):

Linux Mint also uses apt for packages and since it's based on ubuntu the repositories should be compatible. For example for sublime text see this [link](http://blog.hugeaim.com/2012/03/13/install-sublime-text-2-in-linux-mint/). The packages available in the official repositories depend on the distribution for Linux Mint you find a list [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/browse). So since they use the same basic package manager and you find many tutorials about using each other repositories when you google "ubuntu mint repositories" I would say most ubuntu packages should work on mint (without trying).

When you are not sure about switching distributions you can always try them in a virtual machine ([tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player) for ubuntu host) without doing harm to your old system.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one major different between LM and ubuntu . LM comes with some pre-installed applications otherwise LM & Ubuntu are same they are using same repo's.

Answer (score 0):

Linux mint is based on ubuntu so most of the packages in ubuntu are also available in mint, But they use different repositories , So you can't say every package in ubuntu is available in mint repository and vice versa

Why you want change os? You can easily install mint interface(cinnamon) in ubuntu